# MvxSpinner SelectedItem is empty, but in platform side shows selected_item first in ItemSource

Tags: android, xml, mvvmcross

I have MvxSpinner and button which resets its selected Item. On platform-side, the widget does not show empty value, as supposed. It takes first item in source.

ViewModel:

```
    public List<Thing> Protocols
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Thing>()
            {
                new Thing("PPTP")
            //  new Thing("fake")
            };
        }
    }

    private Thing _selectedProtocol = new Thing("");
    public Thing SelectedProtocol
    {
        get { return _selectedProtocol; }
        set { _selectedProtocol = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedProtocol); 
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsCountryListEnabled);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsUsernameEnabled);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsPasswordEnabled);
        }
    }


    public bool IsCountryListEnabled 
    {
        get 
        {
            return !IsEmpty(SelectedProtocol) || IsDedicatedServerTypeSelected;
        }
    }

    private bool IsEmpty(Thing thing) 
    {
        return thing == null || IsEmpty(thing.Caption);
    }

    private bool IsEmpty(string str) 
    {
        return str == null || str.Length == 0;
    }
```

.

```
private Server.ServerType _serverType = Server.ServerType.Static;
public Server.ServerType ServerType
    {
        get { return _serverType; }
        set
        {
            if (_serverType != value) {
                _serverType = value;

                // changed = null; to = new;
                SelectedProtocol = new Thing ();
                SelectedCountry = new Thing ();
                SelectedServer = new Thing ();

                Username = "";
                Password = "";
                switch (_serverType)
                {
                    case Server.ServerType.Free:
                        Username = FreeServerUsername;
                        Password = FreeServerPassword;
                        break;
                }
                RaiseAllPropertiesChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Command which changes all

```
ChangeServerTypeCommand = new MvxCommand<string>(s =>
    {
        if (s == null) return;
        switch (s.ToLower())
        {
            case "free":
                ServerType = Server.ServerType.Free;
                break;
        // ...
    }
```

All code is reachable, checked with breakpoints.

Now the View (not complete, just spinner fragment and all parents)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/settings"

            android:visibility="visible">
            <LinearLayout
                android:background="#f8f8f9"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    local:MvxBind="Visibility IsDedicatedServerTypeSelected,Converter=MyVisibilityGoneInverted;"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="11dp"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

                    <LinearLayout

                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView

                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Countries"
                            android:id="@+id/textView10"
                            android:textColor="#8e8e92"
                            android:textSize="14dp" />

                        <MvxSpinner
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                                android:textColor="#1d1d26"
                                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                                android:textSize="14dp"
                                local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_spinner"
                                local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/item_spinnerdropdown"
                                local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Countries;SelectedItem SelectedCountry; Enabled IsCountryListEnabled" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

ItemSpinner.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:foreground="#000000"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Text Caption" />
```

Dropdown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:foreground="#000000"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    local:MvxBind="Text Caption" />
```

So, the SelectedProtocol already took it's default PPTP value in platform-side,so I cant change it in ViewModel. And all underliyng lists (like server, country) are not enabled, 'cause they depend on Selected* properties of each other, but Protocol is not selected. Same problem for all spinners, but if we'll fix it, will fix all.

Thanks.